# how to add stored procedure in db context DB first .netcore

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, npgsql

i need to add my Postgressql stored procedure to my db context and then use it my controller using EF core,i think in the controller i should use :

```
 var x = db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv('" + dtFrom + @"','" + dtTo + @"','" + regionalManager + @"','" + service_under + @"','" + supervisor + @"')
                            res (o_availability double precision, o_production double precision,o_numberofturbines integer, o_errors_disabled integer,o_failed_battery integer,o_power integer,o_crew_present text)");
```

in db context :

```
  public DbSet<OverviewData> dataInGlance { get; set; }
```

but i think i should add also in the part OnModelCreating modelbuilder,name of my schema is WPV,this SP  returns me the OverviewData class

```
  public class OverviewData
{
    public double Availability { get; set; }
    public string Production { get; set; }
    public int Number_Of_Turbines { get; set; }
    public Int64 ErrorDisabled { get; set; }
    public Int64 FailedBattery { get; set; }
    public Int64 PowerConv { get; set; }
    public string CrewPr { get; set; }
}
```

this class has no key because it just the return result of my SP,but when i run the code i get an error  compaling that i need to ad a key,any help?

Comment: I believe your `DbSet` should be a `DbQuery`.

Comment: @JKL its says DbQuery is obsolete use DbSet instead

Comment: Or actually, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: @JKL it gives me this error Severity Code :The type or namespace name 'Keyless' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You'll first have to tell me what version of EF Core you are using. The `[Keyless]` attribute was introduced in EF Core 5.0.

Comment: @JKL microsoft.Entity.Framework.Core(3.0.0)

Comment: See my answer. You can't use the `[Keyless]` attribute in EFCore 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF Core 3.0 you should override the `OnModelCreating` method in your DatabaseContext class to set `OverviewData` as a keyless entity.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<OverviewData>(od =>
        {
            od.HasNoKey();
        });
}
```